# C# Service worker start an application as background process, how to start the app in normal state?

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-services, background-process

I create a service worker in C# core 6.0 and I install the service in Windows 11. My service starts other applications.
When I run the service from Visual Studio 2022 (F5) it's works well, it opens the other application and I can interact with it.

But when I install the service in Windows, it opens the other application as a background process.

Some code:
**worker.cs**

```
int numberProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("OtherApp").Length;
if (numberProcess < 1)
{
   using (var process = new Process())
   {
      process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\...\OtherApp.exe";
      process.Start();
   }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using WorkerService1;

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

I install the service in Windows with this command using PowerShell as admin:

> New-Service -Name WorkerService -BinaryPathName
> "C:\Users...\WorkerService1.exe" -Description "Keep app Open"
> -DisplayName "WorkerService1" -StartupType Automatic

what should I do ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As of Windows Vista, services cannot directly interact with users ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services)). This change was made to mitigate [Shatter Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatter_attack).

All services run in Terminal Services session 0. All user sessions run in Terminal Services session 1 and higher. Therefore services cannot directly interact with the logged on user as they are running in a different (non-interactive) session.

When you run the application in Visual Studio, you are running it as an *application* in your user context (i.e. running in the same session as you), and therefore you can interact with it.

If you need to interact with the application, you need to either:

- Run it like a normal application
- Run it from Task Scheduler as the logged on user
- Have a Service that can do the work, have another normal application that can be launched and interact with the service.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem, and the solution that I came with is to run the application in sclient *mode* and start the application at at system *startup* , by changing the `outputType`

```
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
```